# How to unpivot a column with different data type SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a query like this

```
SELECT 
    totalvolume = SUM(volume),
    totalusage = SUM(usage),
    percentage = CAST(SUM(usage) * 100 / SUM(volume) as decimal (10,2)),   
    YEAR 
FROM 
    table1
```

and I get table like below

```
|totalvolume|totalusage|percentage|Year
|--------------------------------------
| 100       | 50       | 50.00    |2016  
| 200       | 50       | 25.00    |2015
```

My goal is to make the list table goes like this using `PIVOT`:

```
|Type        |2015  |2016   |
|------------------------   |
| totalvolume| 200  | 100   |
| totalusage | 50   | 50    |
| percentage |25.00|50.00 |
```

So I decide to create this table first using a) `UNPIVOT`:

```
Type        | Value | year
-------------------
totalvolume |100    |2016
totalusage  |50     |2016
percentage  |50.00  |2016 
totalvolume |200    |2015
totalusage  |50     |2015
percentage  |25.00  |2015
```

but in my `UNPIVOT` query

```
SELECT 
    Type, Value, Year
FROM 
    <my table query>
UNPIVOT 
    (value FOR Type IN (totalvolume, totalusage, percentage))
```

There's an error in my SQL:

> The type of column "percentage" conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list

So is there any solution to solve this problem without changing the data type?

If I exclude the percentage column I could get the view I want using pivot so it be like this

```
|Type        |2015  |2016   |
|------------------------   |
| totalvolume| 200  | 100   |
| totalusage | 50   | 50    |
```

But I need the percentage row, too.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Both pivoting and formatting(i.e. 'percentages') are really reporting tool functions, not database functions. What are you doing with this data? Sending it as a report? Use a reporting tool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to have different data types within one column. But you can simulate it by converting all the values to varchar like below

```
SELECT 
    Type, Value, Year
FROM 
    (select 
         convert(varchar(100), totalvolume) as totalvolume,
         convert(varchar(100), totalusage) as totalusage,
         convert(varchar(100), percentage) as totalusage
      from <my table query>) pv
UNPIVOT 
    (value FOR Type IN (totalvolume, totalusage, percentage)) unp
```

Then, if you need to do some calculations, you will have to do reversal conversions.

Comment: So basically I need to convert to varchar to get the unpivot table, then convert it again for the final pivot table?

Comment: You need to convert it again only when you plan to do some calculations, like MAX, MIN, AVG, SUM, etc.  If you just need to display the output then you don't need to convert it back to the original data type.

Comment: For example, if you need then to find the total volume, you should do something like SELECT SUM(CONVERT(int, Value)) FROM unpivot_table WHERE Type = 'totalvolume'

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can convert to a common numeric format for the pivot operation and then format the options for final output.

```
with data(totalvolume, totalusage, percentage, Year) as (
    select 100, 50, 50.00, 2016 union all
    select 200, 50, 25.00, 2015
), converted(totalvolume, totalusage, percentage, Year) as (
    select
        cast(totalvolume as decimal(8, 2)),
        cast(totalusage as decimal(8, 2)),
        cast(percentage as decimal(8, 2)), 
        cast(Year as decimal(8, 2))
    from data
)   
select
    Type,
    case
        when Type in ('totalvolume', 'totalusage') then format(Value, '0')
        when Type = 'percentage'  then format(Value, '0.00\%')
    end as Value,
    format(Year, '0') as Year
from converted unpivot
    (value for Type int (totalvolume, totalusage, percentage)) as unpvt
order by
    Year, Type desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the system tables you could do something like this.  if you wanted to add a where clause or something else you could do it in the dynamic sql.

```
Declare @TableName nvarchar(50), @PrimaryKey nvarchar(50)
Select @TableName = 'TableName', @PrimaryKey = 'PrimaryKey(or unpivot value)'

Declare @JsonConvertColumns nvarchar(max), @UnpivotColumns nvarchar(max)
Declare @SQLQuery nvarchar(max)

select @JsonConvertColumns = Coalesce(@JsonConvertColumns + ',','') + ' string_escape(cast('+columns.name+' as nvarchar(max)), ''JSON'') as ' + columns.name + '' from sys.columns 
    left join sys.tables on tables.object_id = columns.object_id 
     where tables.name = @TableName and columns.name <> @PrimaryKey


select @UnpivotColumns = Coalesce(@UnpivotColumns + ',','') + QuoteName(columns.name) from sys.columns 
    left join sys.tables on tables.object_id = columns.object_id 
     where tables.name = @TableName and columns.name <> @PrimaryKey

Set @SQLQuery = N'SELECT ' + @PrimaryKey + ', FieldName, FieldValue 
FROM (select ' + @PrimaryKey + ', ' + @JsonConvertColumns + ' from ' + @TableName + ') a UNPIVOT
(
       FieldValue
       FOR FieldName IN (' + @UnpivotColumns + ')
       ) as p'

Exec sp_executesql @SQLQuery
```