Properly convert data types in an unpivot statement
I have need to unpivot a table, with fields of varying data types, arranged like this:
PersonalReference   FirstName   LastName
----------------------------------------
123456              John        Smith  

This is to easily compare differences with another dataset which is arranged like this:
PersonalReference   DataDesc   Value
----------------------------------------
123456              FirstName  Jon
123456              LastName   Smith

With the eventual goal being a dataset arranged like this:
PersonalReference   DataDesc   System1Value   System2Value   NoMatch
--------------------------------------------------------------------
123456              FirstName  John            John          1

This code, I think, is syntactically correct:
select
    [PersonalReference],
    [DataDesc],
    [Value]
from
(
    select
        [PersonalReference],
        [Forename],
        [Surname],
        [JoiningDate],
        [LeavingDate],
        [ContractualHours],
        [Position],
        [EmploymentType],
        [Location],
        [PersonalRef_Manager],
        [FullName_Manager],
        [PersonalRef_ClinicalManager],
        [FullName_ClinicalManager],
        [PersonalRef_SeniorManager],
        [FullName_SeniorManager],
        [EmailAddress],
        [UserName],
        [PositionReference],
        [ContractType]
    from MyData
) as [p]
unpivot
(
    [Value] for [DataDesc] in
    (
        [Forename],
        [Surname],
        [JoiningDate],
        [LeavingDate],
        [ContractualHours],
        [Position],
        [EmploymentType],
        [Location],
        [PersonalRef_Manager],
        [FullName_Manager],
        [PersonalRef_ClinicalManager],
        [FullName_ClinicalManager],
        [PersonalRef_SeniorManager],
        [FullName_SeniorManager],
        [EmailAddress],
        [UserName],
        [PositionReference],
        [ContractType]
    )
) as unpvt

But gives me this error:

The type of column "JoiningDate" conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list.

I've tried converting the date and numeric fields in the unpivot list, but this presents the same error:
select
    [PersonalReference],
    [DataDesc],
    [Value]
from
(
    select
        try_convert(nvarchar(50), [PersonalReference]) as [PersonalReference],
        [Forename],
        [Surname],
        try_convert(nvarchar(50), [JoiningDate]) as [JoiningDate],
        try_convert(nvarchar(50), [LeavingDate]) as [LeavingDate],
        try_convert(nvarchar(50), [ContractualHours]) as [ContractualHours],
        [Position],
        [EmploymentType],
        [Location],
        [PersonalRef_Manager],
        [FullName_Manager],
        [PersonalRef_ClinicalManager],
        [FullName_ClinicalManager],
        [PersonalRef_SeniorManager],
        [FullName_SeniorManager],
        [EmailAddress],
        [UserName],
        [PositionReference],
        [ContractType]
    from MyData
) as [p]
unpivot
(
    [Value] for [DataDesc] in
    (
        [Forename],
        [Surname],
        [JoiningDate],
        [LeavingDate],
        [ContractualHours],
        [Position],
        [EmploymentType],
        [Location],
        [PersonalRef_Manager],
        [FullName_Manager],
        [PersonalRef_ClinicalManager],
        [FullName_ClinicalManager],
        [PersonalRef_SeniorManager],
        [FullName_SeniorManager],
        [EmailAddress],
        [UserName],
        [PositionReference],
        [ContractType]
    )
) as unpvt

Short of putting the data into a # table to change all the fields to nvarchar and using that table instead, which I'd rather avoid, I'm a bit stuck on what to try next.
Any help our pointers would be appreciated.

I'll edit this but can I ask why it's a problem? A snapshot of the data or error still clearly displays what it is and is much quicker in a pinch than formatting it all as text.

@DaleK Understood, thanks for the lesson!

The definition of unpivot is you are moving multiple different column values into a single column but different rows. Because you are moving all the pivoted columns into the same column they therefore must have the same datatype, because all values in a column must be the same datatype.

On the face of it I would expect your second example to work, so maybe create a simple DBFiddle showing it not working.

Yes I would expect so too, based on this previously answered question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39066742/how-to-unpivot-a-column-with-different-data-type-sql-server

I can't use DBFiddle as it doesn't have an option for TSQL or MSSQL

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Please provide is with an [mre], @TomCrow . There's not a lot to discuss (in [chat]) if we don't have a copy of a a full reproduction.

Hi @TomCrow , remove the size of VARCHAR and use CAST function

That's terrible advice @FabioAmbrozio . See Bad Habits to Kick : Declaring VARCHAR without (length).

@TomCrow how did you get one? Here is a DB<>Fiddle taking the MS Unpivot Example, changing the last column to a date and then converting all the columns to the same datatype to make the unpivot work.

For it not to be working for you, you must have missed something, but we can't see it without a full MRE (which is why, and I get your frustration, we keep asking for one). However, very often, in the creation of a MRE you will solve the issue yourself, because you need to build up the example carefully from scratch and often spot what you missed when staring at the code. Also in your case, start with 1 column and add a column at a time until you get the issue then it should be clear what the issue is.

Also you say I've tried converting the date and numeric fields in the unpivot list but this presents the same error - is the error exactly the same? Or similar?

FYI if you are converting a date/datetime to a string, you don't really need try_convert because it can't fail.

You might see this even if the columns are all nvarchar(50) if they have different collations https://dbfiddle.uk/O-ln37Wq

Use the same size for VARCHAR([LENGTH]) and the CAST function
SELECT EmployeeID, Attribute, Value
FROM
(
    SELECT EmployeeID,
           CAST(JoiningDate AS VARCHAR(25)) AS JoiningDate,
           CAST(LastPromotionDate AS VARCHAR(25)) AS LastPromotionDate,
           CAST(BonusAmount AS VARCHAR(25)) AS BonusAmount
    FROM MyData
)
as SourceTable
UNPIVOT (
    Value FOR Attribute IN (SourceTable.JoiningDate, SourceTable.LastPromotionDate, SourceTable.BonusAmount)
) AS UnpivotedData;

Complete Solution

This is not good advice. This implicitly converts everything to a varchar(30). The numbers are important: Bad Habits to Kick : Declaring VARCHAR without (length) As for CAST/CONVERT that changes nothing.

Hi, @ThomA. You are correct. I adjust the information

OP has already said I've tried converting the date and numeric fields in the unpivot list - which is the solution you are proposing. So you're not suggesting anything OP hasn't already tried. And CAST is no different to CONVERT (or TRY_CAST/TRY_CONVERT), they all do the same thing.
